# PyCharm to customize {# block myblock #} and {# endblock #}?

Tags: pycharm, customization

I wonder if we can change the font size and/or background color for the **template placeholder/marker** line i.e.

```
{# block myblock #} 
  ... more HTML/Jinja code here
{# endblock #}
```

[Google search](https://www.google.com.vn/#newwindow=1&q=PyCharm+to+customize+%7B%23+block+%23%7D+and+%7B%23+endblock+%23%7D+%3F) or search in PyCharm setting dialog results me nothing helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Colours and font styling (but not font type/size) can be changed for various template elements, via the `Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Django/Jinja2 Template` menu:

[image]

`{# something #}` are comments and yes, their colour and background can be changed independently of other elements.

But if by any chance you mean `{% block myblock %}`/`{% endblock %}` those are tags and Pycharm treats all tags the same way (they can be customized, but not independently - changing a particular tag/tag name affects all tags).

Notes:

- default schemes are read-only, you need to copy them with `Save As` to edit them
- you need to un-check `Use inherited attributes` to activate most buttons on the right
- you need to check `Effects` to activate the font styling dropdown list

Comment: Thanks to give us some hints; though we need some treatment for specific tag not all tag.